# preg_match will not ignore new line breaks

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

Mission : find 10 words and ignore the new line breaks.

I've added the `m` flag for `multi-line` but it has no effect.

```
<?php

$string = "this is line one\n this is line two\n this is line three\n";
$pattern = '/([A-Za-z0-9\.]+ ){1,10}([A-Za-z0-9\.]+)/m';
preg_match($pattern, $string, $matches);
echo $matches[0];
echo "\n";

?>
```

result :

```
this is line one
```

desired result :

```
this is line one this is line two this is line
```

for this desired result I simply removed the new line breaks by hand.

although this desired result is not perfect either.. because it totals to 11 words rather than 10.. I would still be getting closer to my mission if I get this far.

Comment: Replace the space with `\s+`. And you will still need to remove newlines from the result. You can't match a string of text and at the same time remove some repeated pattern inside this match, you will have to use 2 operations.

Comment: And if you need 10 words at most, you just need to adjust the quantifier `'/[A-Za-z0-9.]+(?:\s+[A-Za-z0-9.]+){0,9}/'`

Comment: `m` is to modify the behavior of `^` and `$`, not to make a regex multiline.

Comment: You may also want to look at `\b` as a word boundary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess is that maybe you are trying to write some expression with double-bounded quantifier, such as:

```
(?i)^(\s*[a-z0-9. ]{1,10}(?=\s|$)){0,4}$
```

#### [Demo 1](https://regex101.com/r/YkMWmK/1)

or

```
(?i)^(\s*[a-z0-9. ]{1,10}(?=\s|$)){0,5}
```

#### [Demo 2](https://regex101.com/r/eo0Ay8/1)

or

```
(?i)(\s*[a-z0-9. ]{1,10}(?=\s|$)){0,5}
```

#### [Demo 3](https://regex101.com/r/l1y9zr/1)

or

```
 (?:\S+(?=\s|$)\s*){6}
```

#### [Demo 4](https://regex101.com/r/CAohs7/1/)

or

```
(?:\S+\s*){6}
```

#### [Demo 5](https://regex101.com/r/FCRVOb/1/)

or for capturing the first six words, for instance,

```
^(?:(\S+)\s*)(?:(\S+)\s*)(?:(\S+)\s*)(?:(\S+)\s*)(?:(\S+)\s*)(?:(\S+)\s*)
```

#### [Demo 6](https://regex101.com/r/yZqCN0/1/)

Answer (score 0):

Here is the regex to find 10 words.
Get a single match, then join groups 1-10 using a space.

`(?s)(?<!\S)([A-Za-z0-9\.]+)(?!\S).*?(?<!\S)([A-Za-z0-9\.]+)(?!\S).*?(?<!\S)([A-Za-z0-9\.]+)(?!\S).*?(?<!\S)([A-Za-z0-9\.]+)(?!\S).*?(?<!\S)([A-Za-z0-9\.]+)(?!\S).*?(?<!\S)([A-Za-z0-9\.]+)(?!\S).*?(?<!\S)([A-Za-z0-9\.]+)(?!\S).*?(?<!\S)([A-Za-z0-9\.]+)(?!\S).*?(?<!\S)([A-Za-z0-9\.]+)(?!\S).*?(?<!\S)([A-Za-z0-9\.]+)(?!\S)`

https://regex101.com/r/g0Luco/1